# Get Process ID From Window Title and vice versa

Tags: function, vbscript, pid

I have two functions that can get the PID of an application when its Window Title is given and get the Window Title of an application when its PID is given. Those functions are working fine, but I feel those are bit slower than other functions because both those functions write to external text files to get the CMD output.

Functions:

*Gets the PID when Window Title is given:*

```
Function IntProcessID(StrWindowTitle)
  Dim FSO, WshShell, Tasks, TA, TList, TN, Result

  If StrComp(StrWindowTitle, "", 1) <> 0 Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    TN = FSO.GetTempName
    FSO.GetFolder(WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%LOCALAPPDATA%") + "/Temp").CreateTextFile(TN).Close
    Set TList = FSO.GetFile(WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%LOCALAPPDATA%") + "/Temp/" + TN)

    Result = WshShell.Run("CMD /C TASKLIST /V /FI ""WINDOWTITLE eq " + StrWindowTitle + """ /FO CSV > """ + TList.Path + """", 0, True)

    If Result = 0 Then
      TList.Attributes = 22
      Tasks = Split(FSO.OpenTextFile(TList.Path).ReadAll, VbCrLf)

      For Each Task In Tasks
        TA = Split(Trim(Task), ",")
        If UBound(TA) > 0 Then
          If StrComp(CStr(TA(UBound(TA) + 0)), """" + StrWindowTitle + """", 1) = 0 Then
            IntProcessID = Replace(CStr(TA(LBound(TA) + 1)), """", "")
          End If
        End If
      Next
    Else
      MsgBox "TASKLIST command failed, Error " + CStr(Result)
    End If

    FSO.DeleteFile TList.Path, True

    If Err <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "DeleteFile failed, Error " + CStr(Err) + " - " + CStr(Err.Description)
      Err.Clear
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox "The Window Title cannot be empty"
  End If
End Function
```

*Gets the Window Title when PID is given:*

```
Function StrWindowTitle(IntProcessID)
  Dim FSO, WshShell, Task, TA, TList, TN, Result

  If StrComp(CStr(IntProcessID), "", 1) <> 0 Then
    On Error Resume Next
    Set FSO = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
    TN = FSO.GetTempName
    FSO.GetFolder(WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%LOCALAPPDATA%") + "/Temp").CreateTextFile(TN).Close
    Set TList = FSO.GetFile(WshShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%LOCALAPPDATA%") + "/Temp/" + TN)

    Result = WshShell.Run("CMD /C TASKLIST /V /FI ""PID eq " + CStr(IntProcessID) + """ /FO CSV > """ + TList.Path + """", 0, True)

    If Result = 0 Then
      TList.Attributes = 22
      Task = Split(FSO.OpenTextFile(TList.Path).ReadAll, VbCrLf)
      TA = Split(Trim(Task(1)), ",")
      If UBound(TA) > 1 Then
        If StrComp(CStr(TA(LBound(TA) + 1)), """" + CStr(IntProcessID) + """", 1) = 0 Then
          StrWindowTitle = Replace(CStr(TA(UBound(TA) + 0)), """", "")
        End If
      End If
    Else
      MsgBox "TASKLIST command failed, Error " + CStr(Result)
    End If

    FSO.DeleteFile TList.Path, True

    If Err <> 0 Then
      MsgBox "DeleteFile failed, Error " + CStr(Err) + " - " + CStr(Err.Description)
      Err.Clear
    End If
  Else
    MsgBox "The Process ID cannot be empty"
  End If
End Function
```

Here I used external text files with `Run` method to hide console windows.
Please show me possible ways to make those two functions more short, more fast, more reliable and more stable without getting any CMD/console window flashes while running.

Comment: You know you can just [edit] a question rather than deleting and posting a new one, you asked this same question yesterday. Deleting the question means any associated comments are lost and the history of any edits.

Comment: @Lankymart I know, I deleted it because there are no any associated comments or even any answers with it except the same title. :-|, Sorry for that, I'll remember.

Comment: Still, editing is by far the better method. If a question is unclear and not getting a lot of attention, try modifying it to make it clearer and provide more information. Providing a [mcve] is always a good place to start.

Comment: Deleting and re-posting questions is the same kind of bad habit as bumping threads in forums. Don't do this.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Sorry, should I delete this question or keep it?

Comment: Since you'll end up with one question deleted either way just stick with this one, but please don't do it again.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers I won't do again.

Comment: Now, with that out of the way, why do you think you need to improve performance anyway? I'll admit that writing to temp file isn't the best approach in general, however, VBScript isn't the best language in general either. What you have looks like a rather solid approach to me, so I wouldn't change it as long as it works well enough.

Comment: Another side note (also just for future use), since you're basically asking about improving working code: Code Review might be a better place for this type of question. SO is mostly about getting code to work in the first place.